# Drupal: User name comes up as anonymous 

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view

I'm wondering why my Drupal Views field 'User: name' outputs 'anonymous' for all my users apart from the administrator which outputs 'admin'. I would like to display their user names instead. Anyone know?

Thanks!

UPDATE: So, I figured out that this is because the Authoring information field is empty when Nodes are created. If I edit a Node and add a username in this field the output is as expected. Is there a way to get this field to be prefilled with the username? Can't find any info about this anywhere.

(Using Drupal 6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be filled with the current username by default. Are you hiding/disabling the "Authoring information" fields from non-admin users? That seems the most likely cause.

Comment: Yes, authoring information was hidden. Doh! Thank you! Really appreciated.